# Using Python `eval` function

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

I have the scenario where I need to validate question and answers, I can have multiple answers for the same question.

Below is an example where one question can only have one correct answer, when I use `eval` function to validate this, it is working as expected as shown below in scenario 1.

Scenario 1:

```
q1 = "What_is_your_Name"
options = ["Ash", "Firoz", "Gopal", "Gupta", "Sam"]

# My globals mapping for eval function look like below
# {"What is your Name?": "Ash"}


print(eval("What_is_your_Name in ['Ash', 'Firoz', 'Gopal', 'Gupta', 'Sam']", {'What_is_your_Name': 'Firoz'}))

Result: True
```

Let's say If I have multiple answers for the same question, and If I pass that as a list to the globals key as shown below in scenario 2, it is not working?

Scenario 2:

```
print(eval("What_is_your_Name in ['Ash', 'Firoz', 'Gopal', 'Gupta', 'Sam']", {'What_is_your_Name': ['Firoz', 'Sam']}))

Response: False
```

Is there any workaround for the above Scenario 2? Any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: In scenario 2 `'What_is_your_name'` is a list which does not exists in the list of words so it is false. What is the logic you are trying to apply here when the input is a list of multiple names?

Comment: As in almost all cases of beginners asking about `eval()`, `eval()` is not the right tool here (it rarely is, although it can be very useful in rare cases). Why not `name = input()` followed by `if name in options:` or if you have some sort of dictionary with the questions pre-loaded `if d['"What is your Name?"'] in options:`?

Comment: I wished what Grismar wrote could be engraved in stone.  If you feel you need to use `eval`, you are making a big mistake.  In 30 years of Python programming, I've needed eval() once.  And then only in a highly controlled environment

Comment: What exactly are you asking about here? You would get the same behaviour without ``eval`` as well – ``['Firoz', 'Sam'] in ['Ash', 'Firoz', 'Gopal', 'Gupta', 'Sam']`` can never be true. The title and body seem to indicate you want us to fix your usage of ``eval``, which isn't actually the problem.

Comment: Assuming you don't care about the ``eval`` part but the "list ``in`` list" part, do you want true if *all* or if *any* of the answers are correct?

Answer (score -1):

Putting the suggestion from Grismar in code :

```py
question = 'What is your name ?'
accepted_answers = {
    question: ['Ash', 'Firoz', 'Gopal', 'Gupta', 'Sam'],
}

guess = input(question)
if guess in accepted_answers[question]:
    print("OK")
else:
    print("Nope")
```